# What is going wrong in my calculation of metric tensor for cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am playing around with calculating a line element for cylindrical coordinates. So I tried this in two different ways.

First, I took the position vector to be $$\vec{r} = (x^2+y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\hat{r} + tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})\hat{\phi} + z\hat{z}.$$

Then, I took the position vector to be $$\vec{r} = rcos\phi \hat{x} + rsin\phi \hat{y} + z\hat{z}.$$

For both of these processes, I  used $$e_u = \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial u}$$ to construct the basis vectors where in the first case, $u = x,y,z$ and in the second case, $u=r,\phi ,z$. However, when I go to construct the line element by taking the respective dot products of these basis vectors, I do not get the same result. Since the line element must be invariant, I believe I should get metrics that at least have the same diagonal elements, but in this method, only the position vector $$r = rcos\phi \hat{x} + rsin\phi \hat{y} + z\hat{z}$$ provides the proper diagonal elements on the metric. For the other position vector, $\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial r}$ dotted with itself is not one. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the $\phi\hat{\phi}$ term. The position vector in cylindrical/spherical coordinates is NOT $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}+\phi\hat{\phi}+z\hat{z}$! This is obvious once you write down the definition of $\hat{r},\hat{\phi},\hat{z}$ in terms of $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$. For example,
\begin{align}
\hat{r}=\frac{x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}}{r}.
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\vec{r}:=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}=r\hat{r}+z\hat{z}.
\end{align}

---

To reiterate: just because $\vec{r}=\sum_{i=1}^3x^ie_i$ is the definition of the position vector in cartesian coordinates, it **DOES NOT** mean that if you consider some other coordinate system $(\xi^1,\xi^2,\xi^3)$, with corresponding unit vectors $\{e_{\xi,1},e_{\xi,2},e_{\xi,3}\}$ (the precise definition being $e_{\xi,i}$ being the normalized version of the tangent vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi^i}$), then the position vector is $\vec{r}=\sum_{i=1}^3\xi^i\,e_{\xi,i}$.

Comment: ah got it, thanks !